# How do you orderby nested items from the same table in Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a single table with all my MenuItems in

```
public class MenuItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url  { get; set; }
    public string Attributes { get; set; }
    public List<MenuItem> SubItems { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int Seperator { get; set; }
}
```

I'm then getting my nested hierarchy like this (I've removed the failed ordering)

```
var result = _context.MenuItems.Where(mi => mi.ID == ID)
            .Include(si => si.SubItems)
            .ThenInclude(ssi => ssi.SubItems)
            .ThenInclude(sss => sss.SubItems).FirstOrDefault();
```

Here's the database. Where the OrderId is 0 I don't care about that order, but for anything else, I want the items in that order.

[image]

So I would expect `[File][Test][Edit][Properties][View][Help]`

What I'm getting is `[File][Edit][View][Help][Test][Properties]`

You specify the top-level menu item that you want (in this case 23). and the object that comes back is duly populated with all those menu-items and sub-menu-items.

I'm using react and bootstrap to then display the menu, which it does. So that all works fine, but the items are returned in database (ID) order and I can't seem to get the OrderId column to have any effect.

Any ideas?

Comment: What LINQ are you using? LINQ to SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x?

Answer (score 0):

Use SelectMany to flatten results

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Context _context = new Context();
            var results = _context.MenuItems.SelectMany(x => x.SubItems.Select(y => new
            {
                parentId = x.ID,
                parentName = x.Name,
                child = y
            })).ToList();
                
        }
    }
    public class Context
    {
        public List<MenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }
    }
    public class MenuItem
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public string Attributes { get; set; }
        public List<MenuItem> SubItems { get; set; }
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public int Seperator { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any ordering in your query. I can't see how this will solve my problem. Could you explain a bit more please

Comment: I just did code to get both parent and child.  You can add code to sort and filter.  the code adds two additional columns to your results (parent id and name).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to order your result by ascending OrderId?

```
int requestedMenuItemId = 23;
var result = _context.MenuItems

    // keep only those menu items with ID equal to requestedMenuItemId
    .Where(menuItem => menuItem.ID == requestedMenuItemId)

    // order the remaining menu items by ascending OrderId
    .OrderBy(menuItem => menuItem.OrderId)

    // finally select only the properties that you plan to use
    .Select(menuItem => new
    {
        // Select only the menu items that you actually plan to use
        ID = menuItem.Id,
        Name = menuItem.Name,
        ...

        SubItems = menuItem.SubItems.Select(subItem => new
        {
            ID = subItem.Id,
            Name = subItem.Name,
            ...

            SubItems = subItem.SubItems.Select(ssubItem => new
            {
                ID = ssubItem.Id,
                ...
            })
            .ToList(),
        })
        .ToList(),
    });
```

By the way, I would expect that every menuItem has some foreign key to the parent menu item. Did you forget it?

Comment: Nope, I didn't forget it, if you look at my database image it the column called MenuItemId. I'm using EF and code-first so let that manage the database creation for me. I like your solution and typically that's what I'd normally do. I was hoping to have minimal code and have the database rather than code to do all the heavy lifting.